# Reduce mongodb aggregation with condition

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregation-framework, reduce

I have an array of objects call "extra" with different properties: some objects have "plus" and some haven't.
I want to create inside this "extra" array, 2 different arrays one called "cheap" with all the object that don't have the "plus" property and one called "exp" with only the objects with the "plus" property.
I think I can use the $reduce method in mongodb aggregate with $concatArrays and check with $cond if the property plus exists or not.
Something like that:

Data example:

```
{
    extra: [
        {
            description: "laces",
            type: "exterior",
            plus: '200'
        },
        {
            description: "sole",
            type: "interior"
        },
        {
            description: "logo",
            type: "exterior"
        },
        {
            description: "stud",
            type: "exterior",
            plus: '450'
        }
    ],
}
```

```
 {
    $project: {
        extra: {
            $reduce: {
                input: ['$extra'],
                initialValue: {cheap: [], exp: []},
                $cond: {
                    if: {$eq: ['$$this.plus', null]},
                    then: {
                        in: {
                            cheap: {
                                $concatArrays: ['$$value.cheap', '$$this'],
                            },
                        },
                    },
                    else: {
                        in: {
                            exp: {
                                $concatArrays: ['$$value.exp', '$$this'],
                            },
                        },
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    },
}
```

It doesn't work...I tried many ways or writing the $cond part without luck.
I can't figure it out.
Thank you all.
K.

Comment: Please, provide at least a few records, of what your collection data is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from some minor syntax issues you've had another problem is your understand of the `$ne` operator.

In this case you expect a missing value to be equal to `null`, this is not how Mongo works. so for a document:

```
{ name: "my name" }
```

The aggregation query:

`{ $cond: { $eq: ["$missingField", null] } }`

Will not give true as you expect as missing is not equal to `null`. I took the liberty to fix the syntax issues you've had, this working pipeline is the way to go:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      extra: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$extra",
          initialValue: {
            cheap: [],
            exp: []
          },
          in: {
            cheap: {
              "$concatArrays": [
                "$$value.cheap",
                {
                  $cond: [
                    "$$this.plus",
                    [],
                    [
                      "$$this"
                    ],
                    
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            exp: {
              "$concatArrays": [
                "$$value.exp",
                {
                  $cond: [
                    "$$this.plus",
                    [
                      "$$this"
                    ],
                    []
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        
      },
      
    },
    
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/O-kdjIzRXqN)

One thing to note is that `$cond` evaluates the `plus` field, meaning if the field does exist with a `null` value or a `0` value then it will consider this document matched for the `cheap` array. This is something to consider and change in case these are possible.

Comment: Is it possible to keep just one $cond statement here instead of writing the same code repeatedly?